# Use python script from github on jenkins pipeline

Tags: python, jenkins

Trying to recognize how I can run the python script which is located on GitHub https://github.com/rix0rrr/cover2cover
on Jenkins pipeline

In readme documentation I see 'Add the following "post step" to your Jenkins build:' and command `mkdir -p target/site/cobertura && cover2cover.py target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml src/main/java > target/site/cobertura/coverage.xml`

I am not really familiar with Jenkins and python, so from my understanding before the command above

1. I need somehow to download the script into the Jenkins workspace? Or any possibility to recognize it without downloading it?
2. Have Jenkins tool for cloning/downloading from Github?
3. Should I wrap this command into something like this `sh mkdir folder` `sh python cover2cover.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a Jenkins pipeline with a checkout step ([official docs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/)). You should also check this [blog post](https://ikeptwalking.com/how-to-checkout-code-in-jenkins-pipeline/) on how to do this. In your case it would look something like this:

```
dir('somedir'){
    checkout ([
        $class: 'GitSCM',
        branches:[[name: "master"]],
        doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
        extensions: [
            [$class: 'CleanCheckout']
        ],
        submoduleCfg: [],
        userRemoteConfigs: [[
            url: 'https://github.com/rix0rrr/cover2cover.git',
            credentialsId: ''     <--- put your credentials here if necessary
        ]]
    ])
}
```

Since I added `dir('somedir')` at the top, this would get checked out into `somedir`, and you can then run:

```
mkdir -p target/site/cobertura && cover2cover.py target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml src/main/java > target/site/cobertura/coverage.xml
```

Comment: Should I wrap it `agent { docker { image 'python:3.10.1-alpine' } }` on script call or is it redundant?

Comment: If you already have python in your Jenkins system then it should not be necessary